# JQuery create an array from a data attribute on class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to grab out an array from a data attribute on a table row.

When I run this it returns an array of objects in which I can view there data attributes

```
$('#searchresultstable input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('tr')
```

Chrome's response:

```
[
    <tr class=​"mediafilter-1" data-titleid=​"794">​…​</tr>​,
    <tr class=​"mediafilter-1" data-titleid=​"891">​…​</tr>​, 
    <tr class=​"mediafilter-1" data-titleid=​"1127">​…​</tr>​,
    <tr class=​"mediafilter-1" data-titleid=​"1388">​…​</tr>
​]
```

How ever when I add the data attribute function:

```
$('#searchresultstable input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('tr').data('titleid')
```

Chrome Response: `794`

I know I could probably loop through these with an each and grab then out.  However, I'd like to know how to do this the short hand way, with out the explicit each.  Does anybody know how to grab out these values?

Comment: You'll have to use an `each`, or loop of some variety. When you use `data` on a selector containing multiple elements only the first element will be read.

Comment: What do you think the cleanest way to do that would be then? The map function?

Comment: If you're happy to have the values in an array, then yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can map it like this:

```
var datasArray = $('#searchresultstable input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('tr').map(function(){
     return this.dataset.titleid;// or $(this).data('titleid')
}).get();
```

Comment: `this.dataset` won't work in IE < 11, it would be safer to use the jQuery provided to ensure cross browser support

Comment: Why the `.get()` at the end?

Comment: `Notice the .get() chained at the end. .map() actually returns a jQuery-wrapped collection, even if we return strings out of the callback. We need to use the argument-less version of .get() in order to return a basic JavaScript array that we can work with. `  source: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/